# Separating alloc and init when initializing NSString

Tags: ios4, nsstring, init, alloc

I have a situation where I want to allocate a single NSString object, and assign text to it inside of an if-else block.  When I write the code like this:

```
NSString *string = [NSString alloc];  
if (firstCase) 
    [string initWithString:@"firstCase"];  
else if(secondCase)
    [string initWithString:@"secondCase"];  
[self someFunction:string];
```

I get an error inside of `someFunction` (throws an NSInvalidArgumentException when I try to use `string`).
Also, when I step through my code, once i enter `someFunction`, the console produces a line that says:

> Did you forget to nest alloc and init?

which is referring to `string`.

I've tried the same thing using an NSMutableString and just doing `string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]` and just appending to the string in each if-else block, but I was wondering if anyone knew why the previous way does not produce the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible your running into a case where you are not meeting requirements for your if and else if?? you might want to double check what your cases are... or you might want to default your string to "".  **EDIT:  you can then append to the string after you have declared it to some value using stringByAppendingString**

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
if(case1)
   [string stringByAppendingString:@"desired string"];
elseif(case2)
   [string stringByAppendingString:@"other string"];
```

here is a link to apple's NSString class reference: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: So far I'm always entering the if-else.  If I initialize my string to @"" then I can't change it again in the if-else block can I?  Or is it legal to do this:  
NSString *string = [NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];  
if(case1)  
    [string initWithString:@"case1"]

Comment: @Vince613 take a look at the edits - you can always append to the string. I wouldn't declare your string inside of the if else because the scope of the variable is within the if and else if which will cause you more problems.

Comment: What you said about the scope of the variable only existing within the if-else block I think is exactly what my problem is.  I haven't tried your solution in the edit yet, but it looks like that would work.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Vince613 you can always use NSLog(@"case1 or case2") inside of your if and else if cases to see where your ending up - NSLog(..) can be a really good debugging tool!